# Reordering bootstrap 3.3.7 columns & eliminating height white space between columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to achieve the mobile and desktop view of the following attached image in the lower half. The problem I have right now is, that the violet col begins only after the yellow col is finished.
Here is my html structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">RED</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">YELLOW</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">VIOLET</div>
</div>
```

[image]

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 red">RED<br><br></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 yellow">YELLOW<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 purple">VIOLET</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please give your css code snippet, as other relevant code, as well? Maybe, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Cool thanks. really need to look into CSS Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple solution using **[Grid CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)** & **[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**.

- **First**, I cleaned your HTML markup like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 yellow">YELLOW</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 red">RED</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4  col-lg-4 purple">VIOLET</div>
</div>
```

You can see that I moved the yellow `<div>` to the first position. We'll set change the position with the **grid system** only on a certain viewport, mobile on this case, like so:

**CSS:**

```
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px; /* for demo only */
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px; /* for demo only */
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 200px; /* for demo only */
}

/* Reordering the yellow <div> on mobile version */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container-fluid {
    display: grid;
  }
  .yellow {
    order: 2;
  }
  .red {
    order: 1;
  }
  .purple {
    order: 3;  
  }
}
```

Check this **[code working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/mfgwk0h1/1/)**.

**Edit:**

If you add **`margin`** to the **`<div>`** columns, you'll need to reduce **`col-lg`** & **`col-md`** **utility classes**'s number so it won't break the columns grid.